# Mylyn Redmine Connector Zend Studio 9.x/Eclipse where is it?

Tags: eclipse, redmine, zend-studio, mylyn

there seem to be several sites claiming to have the plugin. The server plugin is installed from here:
http://danmunn.github.com/redmine_mylyn_connector/

Then I need an Eclipse Plugin. But the one from:
http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/Mylyn_Extensions#Redmine
seems to be not working

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Mylyn Connector: Redmine - Redmine-Plugin-Support 0.1.0.201203072118 (net.sf.redmine_mylyn.extensions.feature.feature.group 0.1.0.201203072118)
  Missing requirement: Redmine-Mylyn-Connector Common 0.1.1.201203072118 (net.sf.redmine_mylyn.common 0.1.1.201203072118) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.equinox.log 1.2.0' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Redmine-Mylyn-Connector Core 0.3.3.201203072118 (net.sf.redmine_mylyn.core 0.3.3.201203072118)
    To: bundle net.sf.redmine_mylyn.common 0.1.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Mylyn Connector: Redmine - Redmine-Plugin-Support 0.1.0.201203072118 (net.sf.redmine_mylyn.extensions.feature.feature.group 0.1.0.201203072118)
    To: net.sf.redmine_mylyn.core 0.3.0
```

But the recommended web plugin doesn't exist anymore:
http://download.eclipse.org/tools/mylyn/update/incubator

I thought this would work now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look here ( http://www.redmine.org/boards/1/topics/10923 ) there is an official plugin and some other alternatives...